# Installing Nominatim on CentOS 7?

Tags: postgresql, nominatim

I've installed Nominatim on CentOS 7 because I want to do some reverse geo-coding.

However, when I try to load the and create a Nominatim database with this command:

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file /var/lib/pgsql/indiana-latest.osm.pbf --all --osm2pgsql-cache 4000 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

I get the following error:

```
Create DB
Setup DB
createlang: language "plpgsql" is already installed in database     "nominatim"
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  function st_lineinterpolatepoint(geometry, double precision)  already exists in schema "public"
ERROR: pgsql returned with error code (3)
pgsql returned with error code (3)
```

I've searched the web and can't find any valuable resources to solve my problem.